# Get method parameter values using AspectJ

Tags: methods, parameters, aspectj

I am using AspectJ to capture method calls. Then I need to get the method name and the parameter values passed.
Let's have the following example:

```
Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(lineStart, lineEnd);
and graphics.draw(line);
```

I need to capture all calls to `Graphics2D.draw(Shape)`. I have a pointcut that does this:

```
pointcut captureCallParameters(Shape name) : call(* *(Shape)) && args(name);
```

The problem is when I try to get the value of the parameter (Shape in this method). I get this parameter: `java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double@596e1fb1`

Instad I want to get the points for the shape which is a line in this case.

On the other hand I have also a pointcut that matches the construction of the new line mentioned above and I am able to get the parameters of that line. BUT I don't know how to relate the Draw method with that line constructor. I can have several constructors for `Line`s and I don't know which one of those `Line`s is drawn using the `Draw(line)` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it completely right!

You have indeed caught the Line2D instance that you were looking for. However, you seem to be printing out the `shape` variable in the `System.out.println(shape)` statement. What you have there `java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double@596e1fb1` is the identifier of the variable. You can now access the contents of the variable by calling any available method (for example `shape.getBounds()`).

Furthermore, you can do the following:

```
Line2D line = (Line2D) shape; // cast it to Line2D
line.getX1(); // will give you X1 of your line
line.getX2(); // will give you X2 of your line
```

One last point, here is a better pointcut definition for your use case:

```
pointcut captureCallParameters(Shape shape) : call(* Graphics2D.draw(..)) && args(shape);
```

In your pointcut, you will intercept all the method calls that have the Shape argument. In my version, you will only capture the invocation of the draw() method.